# Dropdown menu with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I have a form and I want to give user ability to choose user in a drop down, but when I return the data it gives me an object, How can I make a drop down select for each user in array.

This is my code

view

```
{!! Form::select('users', array($users),null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a user']) !!}
```

controller

```
$users = User::lists('name');
return view('view')->with('users', $users);
```

now it returns

```
Placeholder
["user1", "user2"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add ID to the list to make it work:

```
$users = User::pluck('name', 'id');
```

Also, use `pluck()` instead of `lists()` because `lists()` is depricated.

Comment: Try `User::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();`.